# Not able to load the data to snowflake table facing Numeric value is not recognized error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks, azure-databricks, snowflake-schema, databricks-sql

I am using the below code in the python data bricks notebook to load the data to the snowflake table.

CAST(O.ITEM_PRODUCT_NAME::TEXT AS VARCHAR) AS PRODUCT_NAME

I am facing the below error

```
100038 (22018): Numeric value 'SAaL Tuvarinerine Neano sBites (53mg x 30) 100mg (S) (100mg, case of 60)' is not recognized',
```

The input string contains special characters and alpha numeric I need to load the data as a string to snowflake table. Pleae find sample data

```
Select as Elites Cartsridge - 1g 20box GSC (1g) FND,PRE-ROLL,(S) QUEENt OF SOUL,,,1G (1g, case of 25) CL Lord Flower Trim Preroll 1g (H) (1.0g, case of 300) Blueberry Indica 10 Padfck Gusgmmies (100mg THC, case of 50) SELECT Disphdosable Cart - Tangie - 0.3g (0.3g, case of 20) Grassrootds Shorties Pre-Rolls It's Mimosa (2g, case of 10) Capsulses - East Coast Sour Diesel RSO - 10mg (10pk, 100mg) (10mg. 10pk
```

Comment: Please update your question with the entire INSERT statement you are running and the ddl for the table you are loading into. But it appears from the error message that you are trying to load a text value into a numeric column

Comment: and post target table structure too.

Answer (score 0):

`O.ITEM_PRODUCT_NAME::TEXT` is snowflake syntax to cast the data to TEXT/VARCHAR so then CAST is redundant.

The error message implies you are doing something like:

```
SELECT 
  'this is not numeric' as a,
   to_number(a) as b;
```

which gives:

> Numeric value 'this is not numeric' is not recognized

in which case you want to use TRY_TO_NUMBER

```
SELECT 
    column1 as a, 
    try_to_number(a) as b
from values 
    ('this is not numeric'),
    ('12345')
;
```

[image]

Comment: The input string contains special characters and alpha numeric I need to load the data as a string to snowflake table.  Pleae find sample data    Selectas Elites Cartsridge - 1g 20box GSC (1g)
FND,PRE-ROLL,(S) QUEENt OF SOUL,,,1G (1g, case of 25)
CL Lord Flower Trim Preroll 1g (H) (1.0g, case of 300)
Blueberry Indica 10 Padfck Gusgmmies (100mg THC, case of 50)
SELECT Disphdosable Cart - Tangie - 0.3g (0.3g, case of 20)
Grassrootds Shorties Pre-Rolls It's Mimosa (2g, case of 10)
Capsulses - East Coast Sour Diesel RSO - 10mg (10pk, 100mg) (10mg. 10pk)

Comment: Please don't add additional information in comments - update your question, formatting data as tables so that it is readable. Again, if you don't update your question with the information I and Koushik requested in the comments then no-one is going to be able to help you.